# Initialize class while boosting Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a custom class:

```
class A {
   private items = [];
   constructor() {
       for(let i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
           this.items.push(i);
        }
   }

   public get(){
       return this.items;
   }
}
```

I need to create instance of this class once while boosting Angular, then I want to get instance  of A everywhere in application,in another custom service. How to register this class A right?

Another custom service is:

```
class ButtonUsage {
  public constructor(instance a: A) {
     a.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: add `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })` decorator to class A

Comment: Then register this class in `providers: []`?

Comment: Which one, or both?

Comment: `{ providedIn: "root" }` registers it to root injector. no need to add it to `providers: []`

Comment: Then how to use `A` in another service, just inject it?

Comment: yes just inject it `constructor(private instanceA: A)`

Comment: its bothers me did you mean booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injectable decorator is required so that service can be injected into other services or components.

*a.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) // global scope singleton
export class A {
  ...
}
```

*button-usage.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { A } from './a';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ButtonUsage {
  constructor(
    private a: A,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `ButtonUsage` is also root registered>

Comment: I use like you said: `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ButtonUsage {}` it return me unclear error message: `core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[String]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[String]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
    at `

Comment: 1. Almost all services should be defined in dependency injector container (there small exceptions). If your `ButtonUsage` is component it will be defined in some NgModule so it wont require additional Injectable decorator just Component wil be enough.

2. That looks little bit like you tried to inject some string check this one for example how to do that: http://www.angular.love/2018/03/09/angular-injectiontoken/ I would need to see your NgModule setup to help more with that error